# Handle audio interruptions AVAudioPlayer

Tags: iphone, delegates, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

I am playing "sound effects" in my app when buttons are clicked and such and I have been having some difficulties getting the delegates to work properly within the AVAudioPlayer class to keep the music playing after the sound. I have the framework imported and delegates set but I can not seem to get the AVAudioSession shared instance to work... I know I am missing something but can not seem to find a clear answer anywhere even within apples docs. Here is the code I am using trying to accomplish this.

```
#import "AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h
#import "MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h"

@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate, MPMediaPlayback   
> {
```

When a button is pushed

```
-(IBAction)About
{ 
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"button" ofType:@"caf"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play]; 

    AboutViewController *about = [[AboutViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentModalViewController:about animated:YES];

    NSString *path1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"move" ofType:@"caf"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio1 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path1] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio1 play];     
}
```

Delegates trying to either play my sound as a "ambient noise" or just resume play after my sound happens

```
-(void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{

}

-(void)audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur:(AVAudioPlayer *)player error:(NSError *)error
{

}

-(void)audioPlayerBeginInterruption:(AVAudioPlayer *)player
{

}

-(void)audioPlayerEndInterruption:(AVAudioPlayer *)player withFlags:(NSUInteger)flags
{
    if (flags)
    {
        AVAudioPlayer *audio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] init];
        [audio setDelegate:self];
        [audio play];
    }
}
```

Now the last delegate from what I understand is the only delegate of use really in my case and what I have will not work since I need to be using the `[AVAudioSession SharedInstance]` like this but I can not seem to get the `AVAudioSession` to work!

```
-(void)audioPlayerEndInterruption:(AVAudioPlayer *)player withFlags:(NSUInteger)flags
{
    if (flags == AVAudioSessionFlags_ResumePlay)
    {
        [player play];
    }
 }
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I basically just need to know how to get the `[AVAudio SharedInstance]` so if anyone knows what class I need to import or framework I need to add to get this working it would be very much obliged!

Thanks